# mySql query is not printing all characters. How to show all characters

Tags: mysql, terminal, putty, windows-console

Table has got all the values. perfectly. but some times its not printing all characters and is using | ( meaning before that characters are same as of previous record). How can i see entire characters. I'm using putty to access a remote mysql db. The first one is primary key with auto_increment. Still I'm facing the issue. Please help me. 
[image]

Comment: you are showing us an image.  i have no way to know how to debug this if there is no code, or test database to query against.

Comment: couldn't you just use phpmyadmin instead of shell?

Comment: @Alex right now, I'm logging into a remote unix vm which has mysql db on it. We do ssh to that vm then loggin into mysql. using commands. like -u -p etc. 
I tried logging in from workbench in my laptop. but couldn't. Is there any way i can do this? I dont have admin access too. :( this terminal is making my life hard.